# Repeated Layouts in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to use an MVC mechanism to creat repeatable layouts? 
For example: 
We have snippets of HTML all over the show that MUST have the same elements and attributs, but can have separate content (the content can be a bunch of HTML as well).

I was leaning towards HTML helpers, but this doesn't seem to allow something like this:

```
@Html.Business(Name, Attr2)
{
    <em>Do Not Contact</em>
    <p>Arbitrary text</p>
}
@Html.Business(Name, Attr2)
{
    <table>...</table>
}
```

The key point here is that the embedded HTML is arbitrary and won't have parameters available to the Helper method.

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: You may be referring to layout partials?  Just create a view (.vbhtml or .cshtml) and use @Html.Partial("YourViewName")

Comment: Ok, can you give an example? Partials require a Model as far as I know, in this case that won't necessarily be the case, but we might still want to pass in variables as parameters? I'd be willing to rethink this.

Comment: The closest example I could give is the BeginForm helper which allows you to provide some basics for the form element itself as well as throwing in a bunch of HTML inside it.

Comment: Same element and attributes, but your snippet shows different elements and attributes using the same helpers. Yout snippet doesn't describe what you are trying to do.... In fact, it's not even proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up Layouts and Templates. A Layout is a base frame that serves as a common container for all your views. A Template (what you should be looking for) is a way of displaying a specific (generally specific) type of data.

There are two basic ways to implement Templates.

---

The first one is by defining it as the default Template. This is done by a simple Naming convention. Just make sure your .cshtml file has the same name as your Entity class name and place it in :

> /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/.cshtml

After that, whenever you want to display your entity using the template, use the `@Html.DisplayFor()` helper, supplying your object accordingly.

Alternatively, if you wish to call the template differently or don't want the template to be used in every circumstances, you may specify the template name using a `[UIHint("TemplateName")]` attribute on your entity or passing the template name in your DisplayFor().

---

The second method would be using Partial Views. You can create a partial view of how you wish to display the data and use `@Html.RenderPartial("TemplateName", object)`

---

In both scenarios, the Template / Partial view can be created easly with the VS interface:

- Right click on the DisplayTemplate (or other location) folder you want to create your template in, then click on `Add>View...`
- Type in the name, check the `Create a strongly-typed view`
- Select the appropriate object (if you cant find it, you can do it manually after, but I suggest at least picking something to simplify the work)
- Select `Details` as the Scaffold template
- Check the `Create as partial view` box
- Uncheck the `Use a layout or master page`

Make sure the `@model <Entity Name>` matches the object you will pass then make any modification you wish to how it will be displayed.

Enjoy!

-**Edit**-

Note: After reading your post once more, I realise that might not be exactly what you are asking for, but it is very unclear. Can you explain in more details what you are trying to acheive instead of **how** you are trying to do it?

The code snippet you wrote doesn't really make sense.